# Use special character in custom VSTS PowerShell script task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, msbuild-task

I am currently facing the problem that I would like to set the Copyright of my AssemblyInfo dynamically during the VSTS build to something like this:

> © 2012-2018 Company Name

but the 2018 should be set dynamically representing the current year.
Therefor I tried to set a global build variable to something like this:

> © 2012-$(Date:yyyy) Company Name

Here the copyright special character works fine but the date does not work at this place so the next thing I tried was to make a custom PowerShell script build task with an inline script.
I set again my global variable ("Copyright") this time to

> -set during build-

and in the inline script I tried to replace the value like this:

```
$date=$(Get-Date -Format yyyy);
$_Copyright = "© 2012-$date Company Name";
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Copyright]$_Copyright";
```

Now I got my dynamic date working but on my shipped dlls I get
"c 2012-2018 Company Name"
with a 'c' instead of the '©'.

So I replaced it with [char]0x00A9:

```
$date=$(Get-Date -Format yyyy);
$_Copyright = [char]0x00A9 + " 2012-$date Company Name";
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Copyright]$_Copyright";
```

But nothing changes in the result:
"c 2012-2018 Company Name"

Although on my local machine my PowerShell gives me for [char]0x00A9  the '©' sign.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue.

Seems the [logging command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) cannot recognize the symbol ©. So we cannot set the variable which including the © as the value by below command:

`Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Copyright]$_Copyright"`

In your scenario you can try below workarounds:

**1, Using `Copyright (c)` instead of `Copyright ©`, the logging command can recognize the string `(c)`:**

```
$date=$(Get-Date -Format yyyy);
$_Copyright = "(c) 2012-$date Company Name";
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Copyright]$_Copyright";
```

**2, Combine variables:**

1) Set a global build variable e.g.: `$(Symbol)` and set `©` as the value

2) Set a date variable using logging command :

```
$date=$(Get-Date -Format yyyy);
$Company= "2012-$date Company Name";
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Company]$Company";
```

3) Use the variable `$(Symbol)$(Company)` together to get the entire Copyright string.

Alternately you can directly use `©$(Company)` to check if that works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I am going for your suggested workaround 2 - Combine Variables;
Both approaches `$(Symbol)$(Copyright)` and `©$(Copyright)` work fine for me. Quite a pity that Unicode is not supported and since I don't think that gonna be changed anytime soon I gonna mark this question as solved.